# Power BI Calculating Max Values filtered by DatesBetween

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, max

I am creating a comparison chart in Power BI for attendance (measured at 11:00) regarding Covid and I would like to get the maximum, minimum and average attendance for a previous lockdown, so a set period. (so the last 4 lines in the reproducible sample are not being used for any calculation). Could someone please help me?

In addition, I come from Python and use the print() and print(type()) command a lot for evaluation. Is there such a method in DAX, or how would you do this otherwise?

**Minimal reproducible sample**

[image]

**Desired Result**

[image]

Attempt:

```
/* START QUERY BUILDER */
DEFINE
VAR StartDate =
    DATE ( 2020, 04, 12 )
VAR EndDate =
    DATE ( 2020, 05, 30 )
    
EVALUATE
VAR MaxAttendance =
CALCULATE (
    MAXX (
        'DATA'[Employees present at 11:00],
        FILTER (
            'DATA'[Date],
            DATESBETWEEN (
                'DATA'[Date],
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            )
        )
    )
)
VAR MinAttendance =
CALCULATE (
    MINX (
        'DATA'[Employees present at 11:00],
        FILTER (
            'DATA'[Date],
            DATESBETWEEN (
                'DATA'[Date],
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            )
        )
    )
)
VARAverageAttendance =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        'DATA'[Employees present at 11:00],
        FILTER (
            'DATA'[Date],
            DATESBETWEEN (
                'DATA'[Date],
                StartDate,
                EndDate
            )
        )
    )
)

RETURN
    MaxAttendance
    MinAttendance
    AverageAttendance

/* END QUERY BUILDER */
```

Comment: How MaxAttendance for Location A is 14 where I can see its 25?

Comment: The timeframe for which the values must be returned is in the past (2020). The new data is in 2021, which I don't need.

Comment: Is that date range selection is dynamic? or you need Yearly Max, Min and Average?

Comment: No, the date range is static. The startdate is 2020, 04, 12 and the enddate is 2020, 05, 30. I would like to compare current values as a linechart with these historical values as horizontal lines in the chart. I think that 3 calculated measures would do the trick. I have now manually done this, by setting the values as a static integer, but the historical values of course do not change when I apply the filter for another office.